# QueryTask problem in Android ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-android, query-task

I use ArcGIS  in my Android app. I use query task for search in mapserver and show a feature by another color. I mean when a feature find should change color.my code work right but can not change color feature. This is my code:

Comment: please help friends

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: @Vince post edited.

Comment: Now please [edit] to add details that include the exact versions of software in use, and what you mean by that it both "work right but can not change color feature". It's not possible for us to debug your code.

Comment: please help my friends

Comment: Please remove your "please help" requests. They do ***not*** improve the likelihood of response (since it implies that the volunteers here, who are looking to help, don't want to help *you*). The best way to obtain an answer is to write a thorough question (which you don't yet appear to have achieved). After that, you need to have luck that your question is within the skill set of those visiting the site. No amount of pleading can change that.